# bad interpreter while attempting pip install flask

Tags: python, flask

I do have Flask installed at my root directory, however whenever I change directories and run a virutalenv venv to attempt to install flask via pip install flask I receive the following error

`bash: /home/phillipsk/rampup/sql/venv/bin/easy_install: /home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Here are the contents of the venv directory

`activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  activate_this.py  easy_install  easy_install-2.7  pip  pip2  pip2.7  python  python2  python2.7`

I can run `/home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/bin/python`

and the python interpreter opens

> Python 2.7.6

here is the ls -l of

> /home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/bin/python

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3349512 Aug 15 13:11 /home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/bin/python`

This is my attempt at running `pip install flask`

```
>     (venv)phillipsk@phillips:~/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/bin$ pip install flask Downloading/unpacking flask Cleaning up... Exception: Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py",
> line 122, in main
>         status = self.run(options, args)   File "/home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py",
> line 278, in run
>         requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)   File
> "/home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py",
> line 1153, in prepare_files
>         location = req_to_install.build_location(self.build_dir, not self.is_download)   File
> "/home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py",
> line 218, in build_location
>         _make_build_dir(build_dir)   File "/home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py",
> line 1527, in _make_build_dir
>         os.makedirs(build_dir)   File "/home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/lib/python2.7/os.py", line
> 157, in makedirs
>         mkdir(name, mode) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/build'
>     
>     Storing debug log for failure in /home/phillipsk/.pip/pip.log
```

`sudo pip install flask` does work but regardless after running either pip commands I immediately enter into a python interpreter and `import flask` with no success

Comment: Can you run `/home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/bin/python` manually?

Comment: Please show `ls -l /home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/bin/python` and if it's a symlink show `ls -l` for its target.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution, try changing ownership of your *venv* folder and all underlying files and folders:

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusersgroup venv
```

then reactivate virtualenv and try instaling flask without *sudo*.

Btw. if you are using *sudo* when creating virtualenvs, you shouldn't. Run *virtualenv /path/to/virtualenv* without *sudo* and logged in as a regular user, activate it and then *pip install* stuff. Hope this helps.

As a sidenote look into *virtualenvwrapper* project. It might make things easier for you in the future. 
http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

the directory is owned by root,
you said it yourself

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3349512 Aug 15 13:11 /home/phillipsk/rampup/webapp/sql/venv/bin/python
```

so to do it just

```
sudo pip install flask
```

Comment: I said above, after I sudo install, I enter into a python interpreter and import flask still does not work